# How does Chocolatey know which packages are installed locally?

Tags: chocolatey

How does [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) determine which packages are installed on the local system?

Somehow `choco list -localonly` lists packages installed locally and invokes `nuget.exe` in the process. In NuGet I know `packages.config` lists installed packages, but in Chocolatey I don't seem to find a similar file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`choco list -lo`](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-list) only lists the latest versions of the packages you have installed.

Old choco invoked nuget.exe, new choco (0.9.9+) does it directly since it has nuget.core built-in.

It does a list against `%ChocolateyInstall%\lib` when you call `list -lo`. If several versions of the same package exist, only the latest version will be listed. Use `list -lo -a` to show all versions of the same package available locally.

Further, it is not based on folders, but on the actual nupkg files in those folders.

If you want a list of programs and features, add `-i` as an option. See `choco list -h` or the [docs page](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-list) for details.

Comment: Thanks @ferventcoder! In my lib dir is much more than what is just listed in list -lo. How does choco really determine what's installed and what's just and old version lying around?

Comment: @Christian So chocolatey loads up nuget's package manager and points to the local directory. It looks at the nuget packages that are there at the latest versions. It's not a simple folder based scan to see what is installed. To see all the old versions as well you should look at `choco list -h` to get the all versions option to use with `choco list -lo`.

Comment: @Christian I don't understand this: "and what's just and old version lying around?" What do you mean by that?

Comment: What I meant was: If I enter `choco list -lo` I get as output for example `putty 0.64`, whereas choco's lib directory and `choco list -lo -AllVersions` show `putty 0.63` AND `putty 0.64`. I was trying to determine the logic that choco uses to determine what's installed and what's not, i.e. trying to understand the logic why it only shows `putty 0.64` (the latest version). Now I understand that it does not determine what's installed when running `choco list -lo`, but simply shows the latest version number. Thank you!

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect my current understanding: `list -lo` does not list *installed* packages as I thought, it lists the latest version of the *locally available* pacakges.

The following question remains: Is there a way to list locally *installed* packages?

Comment: Not quite right. I updated the edit. Perhaps you are using the term "package" and you mean to state "software" as in what is installed in programs and features?

Comment: Installed packages of software through choco will be in the `choco list -lo` - and if you need all versions and prereleases you should adjust your query accordingly `choco list -lo -pre -all`.

Comment: OK, many thanks for clarifying! Yes, I mean *installed software* as in programs and features.

Comment: I will update the comment for how you can include the programs and features list

Comment: @Christian there is a way to get to the ARP (programs and features) list as well. I'd suggest using the help menus in choco. They are actually quite good now. `choco list -h`